# How would a person function if they were in orgasm literally all the time, biologically speaking?

Tags: science-based, biology, humans, psychology, sex

Say a new medical disorder cropped up where a person, after whatever guilty pleasure they had, found themselves trapped in orgasm. As in, the orgasm happens, the flood of euphoric dopamine rushes in, their brain activity soars, and then it just.. never goes away. They're trapped in that orgasmic state 24/7 and their brain never comes back down from it nor releases. Permanent Orgasm.

There are real life cases where people get headaches or hiccups for years, with those examples it's not as completely absurd to imagine this disorder, if still a bit so. What would their life be like from there, what challenges would they face? Physically, personally, socially, mentally, medically even? I'm genuinely curious.

This would also be a tantric orgasm essentially, with primarily the focus on the mental, physiological effects of orgasm lingering indefinitely on the brain, but also with slight involuntarily contractions and erections/stiffness of genitals. Without ejaculating necessarily.

Comment: How is this relevant to building a world?

Comment: I'm interested in the characterization of such a condition for fictional purposes.

Comment: You may need to be specific about what parts of an orgasm you want to be included.  The typical definition includes involuntary muscle contractions which would make this a lot more difficult to live than if one is only interested in the euphoria effects.

Comment: Well the contractions and the typical change in brain physiology, which is usually temporary but in this case permanent.
Ejaculation is naturally omitted since I think it'd be unreasonable to expect someone to ejaculate nonstop, I'll clarify that uptop.

Comment: -1 for not googling about similar illness, relatively well known, and if you would have question after reading about it and you will still have question to ask, you could produce better question based on that information from real cases.

Comment: It can t be 24/7 as the reserves of dopamine in your brain need to be replenished.

Answer (score 10):

[It's actually a real thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_genital_arousal_disorder). Well, very close. There are documented and confirmed cases of people who live in a constant state of arousal, with frequent orgasms. Not quite constant, but very close.

There's plenty of documentation on the difficulties people with the disorder go though. Sufferers report extreme difficulty in concentrating and in some cases that the experience borders on or is painful.

Comment: Ouch, how terrifying. I cannot imagine how uncomfortable that would be.

Comment: Yes, I've seen reports of this too. Even saw a TV interview with someone who had the problem.

Comment: They say erections lasting more than 4 hours are hospital worthy for a reason.

Answer (score 5):

Tantric practice (in its original form) had this as a goal. The state of orgasm is a higher level of consciousness, and brain scans have shown monks with years of meditation practice have patterns of brain activity similar to sexual orgasm.

So it would depend if the person had the training to channel the energy effectively.

If not, in the worst case they would trip the "overload" button and black out for a few seconds. Regularly. It would be like epilepsy.

With a bit more control, they would be able to remain conscious, but may have physical twitches and shaking.

More control again, and they would be like someone on DMT or ecstasy.

Full control, and they would be like a saint alive with the Holy Spirit.

**Erection and Ejaculation**

Neither erection nor ejaculation is necessary for orgasm. In fact, the more practised the Tantric, the lower the association of orgasm with either erection or ejaculation.